# drawing lines, and getting error code # 1009

Tags: actionscript, draw, lines

I'm having a problem I can't seem to solve.  I'm making an animation wich draws a line after a moving object (circle on a guide line).  This circle is a movieclip and I have many lines to draw up.  So, I put many of them on separate scenes. I've created buttons from movieclips, and when pressed it draws a line. I got everything to work properly, but when one line is drawn, and you press the same button to get the same line drawn again I get the error code: `#1009 cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.`

I think that it's because the graphics is still there but I can't seem to clear it before it draws again. I have used `graphics.clear();` but that just clears all, so when it "draws" again it doesn't show, only the movieclip-animation works. What is the problem here?

My code for the line drawing is:

```
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.events.Event;

var shape = new Shape();
shape.graphics.lineStyle(2,0xFF0000);
shape.graphics.moveTo(ani1.x, ani1.y);
addChild(shape);

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

function loop(event:Event):void
{
    shape.graphics.lineTo(ani1.x, ani1.y);
}
```

and the code for the buttons is:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();

menu_button1.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClick);

function buttonClick (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndPlay(2, "AniDel1");
}
```

and all of the animations has a `stop();` at the end.

Comment: try getting rid of the scenes, they are evil. and i don't know what the scope/lifetime of your variable is when you are using scenes. the error may come from the ENTER_FRAME listener: it's still running, but shape is not defined anymore, because you switched scenes ...

Comment: I tried that now, but it doesn't work.. the same error code pops up:/ but thanks for helping out:) any other idea?

Comment: 'ani1' is the circle right!? is the circle present on all frames of the timeline? do you have multiple keyframes on your timeline, is the name of the circle set in every keyframe? does the errormsg say anything about the line of code the null-pointer-exception happens?

Comment: ok, i did some changes yesterday and got it to work better,but still something is wrong. 'ani1' is the circle an it starts in the 2nd frame, with the drawing code above. (in frame 1 is the code for the buttons) I't ends at frame 230 with a keyframe. in this keyframe is the stop code. (the circle has the same name in all frames) and since there are more animations the whole thiong stops at frame 686.

Comment: there is frames for each layer to this point (not keyframes, just a frame with the white rectangle in it). I used som code yesterday; ani1.graphics.clear(); and ani1.visible = false; in the begunning at the new animation, just trying to delete or hide it,and it works as long as they play in correct order, but when you just choose a random button it gets many errors..when ctrl+enter: error 1010: a term is undefined an has no properties, frame 1. (all the buttons are movieclips with instancenames)

Comment: do you still get the same error? then try also putting the animation into the first frame and hiding it by moving it of stage and having a keyframe in the second frames which puts it where it belongs...

Comment: when you click one button, each animation before this one gets this error:1009 cannot access a property...:MainTimeline/loop(),  :MainTimeline/loop13() an so on..

Answer (score 0):

i put together an example fla for you: [anitest.fla.zip](http://labs.beta-interactive.de/anitest.fla.zip)

hope this solves your problem.

Comment: hnaks:) this is great! but I got yhis to work, the only thing is the problem when you make more buttons, and more lines drawn.                                                            can you please make an example wich has button "a" and button "b" with two drawings wich draw with  for example 3 or 4 frames after the first one,(on different ayers) and when you click button "a" it draws theese, and when you click "b" it clears whats drawn in "a" and draws whats on "b"?...and if ckicked "a" and "a" again it just clears it and draw from scratch? I'm no good explaining:p but you understand?:)

Comment: @cat you should think about coding in classes and getting rid of the timeline. the more complicated your projects get, the harder it'll be to maintain everything on the timeline. create your animation assets in the IDE export them all as SWC and write a class that controls everything.